# Can't seem to figure out the logic to finish my jquery hangman game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a hangman game for my Javascript class and I'm stuck on the logic. I can't figure out how to allow the user to hit a key like "a" and replace the underscore with the letter that was pressed. This is what I have so far: `

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var words = [
    ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e"],
    ["b", "a", "n", "a", "n", "a"],
    ["o", "r", "a", "n", "g", "e"],
    ["m", "a", "n", "g", "o"],
    ["s", "t", "r", "a", "w", "b", "e", "r", "r", "y"],
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length - 1)];

$("#newWord").click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < (word.length); i++) {
        document.write("_ ");
    }
});
```

});
`

Comment: Search a little more before asking for help so fast next time. :) `.click` is a deprecated way of writing `.on('click')`, and the `.on()` event handler supports many events including keyboard-related ones. Read about more events such as `keydown` (which you could use for this) in the jQuery API here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: @Jon Uleis - are you sure that .click() is deprecated - whilst the more verbose .on('click'... ) is arguablly better - I am sure that .click() is still valid and not deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

make a json with all keycodes and letters

```
Var json = [
    65: "a", 
    66: "b",
    67: "c"
    etc ...
];
```

And document write from there

```
$("#newWord").on("keypress keydown", function(e){

    Document.write(json[e.keyCode]);

});
```

[**keyCodes**](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)